# Loop through custom list of maps - Terraform

Tags: terraform

I've created a custom `locals` variable where I use  `if`-statement to filter the values.

E.g

```
locals {
 data = flatten([for value1 in object1 : [
          for value2 in value1.object2 : [ 
            for value3 in value2.object3 : 
 startwith(value3.id, "1") ? { 
      data1 = ...
      data2 = ...
      data3 = ...
    } : {}
  ]])
 ]
}
output = [
  {
    data1 = "a"
    data2 = "a"
    data3 = "a"
  },
  {},
  {},
  {
    data1 = "b"
    data2 = "b"
    data3 = "b"
  }
]
```

However I struggle to loop through this variable inside inside a resource, because some of the maps are empty.

#Attempt 1

```
resource "DATA" "my_resource" {
  for_each = local.data
  
  name = each.value.data1
  value = each.value.data2
  description = each.value.data3
...
}

ERROR: 
local.data is tuple with 4 element
```

#Attempt 2

```
resource "DATA" "my_resource" {
  for_each = { for key, value in local.data : key => value
  
  name = each.value.data1
  value = each.value.data2
  description = each.value.data3
...


ERROR:
...
 This map does not have an element with the key "data1"
...
 This map does not have an element with the key "data2"
...
 This map does not have an element with the key "data3"
```

**EDIT:**

I'm now looking for a more effective solution than this:

```
# Check if a key exists, meaning it's not empty
for_each = { for k, v in local.data : v => v if contains(keys(v), "data1")}
```

Comment: What do you meany by "more effective solution"? If its working, why change it?

Comment: I'm just curious if I could do anything different, by using more of the built-in functions. E.g is it possible for me to do something in the `locals` which removes the need for the `if` statement inside the `for_each`. @Marcin

Comment: So just move `{ for k, v in local.data : v => v if contains(keys(v), "data1")}` to locals. Not sure what you are after.

Comment: @Marcin . Can I have a filter / `if`-statmenet in in my `for`-loop in `locals`, without having a else condition where I return empty map `{}` ?

Comment: @Marcin, ended up using my solution, but i'll approve yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [lookup](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/lookup) to check for an existence of a key, and provide a default value:

```
resource "DATA" "my_resource" {

  for_each = { for key, value in local.data : key => value}
  
  name = lookup(each.value, "data1", null)
  value = lookup(each.value, "data2", null)
  description = lookup(each.value, "data3", null)
...
}
```